# how to take the value of a variable in a loop after each iteration?

Tags: c++, loops, variables, vector

I am writing some code to figure out a total grade. It currently is able to take in all of the inputs required, but I don't know how to take the sum after each iteration so that I can add them all together before outputting the final grade. Is there some simple way to do that?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector> 

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> v;

    double y;
    double z;
    double sum;
    double o;
    int n;

    cout << "how many quizzes/projects/major assignments do you have?" << endl;
    cin >> n;

    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        v.push_back(i);

    z = v.front();
    while (z != v.back()) {

        cout << "what is the weight of test # " << z + 1 << " as a decimal" << endl;

        cin >> y;

        cout << "what was your grade on test # " << z + 1 << endl;

        cin >> o;

        sum = y * o;

        z = z + 1;
    }

    cout << sum << endl;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You named a variable "sum", but you use it to store *one* weighted score. Consider `sum = sum + y*o;`

Comment: I'm not sure what you need with vector variable `v`. You're only using its first and last elements, and you aren't changing them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You Can use sum variable again to add whole sum, below is the modification in the code, that will help you to find out whole sum

```
   /******************************************************************************

                          Online C++ Compiler.
           Code, Compile, Run and Debug C++ program online.
       Write your code in this editor and press "Run" button to compile and execute it.

     ******************************************************************************/

#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector> 

using namespace std;

int main()
{
vector<int> v;
double y;
double z;
double sum=0;
double o;
int n;

cout << "how many quizzes/projects/major assignments do you have?" << endl;
cin >> n;

for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    v.push_back(i);

z = v.front();
while (z != v.back()) {

    cout << "what is the weight of test # " << z + 1 << " as a decimal" << endl;

    cin >> y;

    cout << "what was your grade on test # " << z + 1 << endl;

    cin >> o;

    sum = sum+(y * o);

    z = z + 1;
}


cout<<"SUm is :" << sum << endl;


}
```

Comment: brackets are just used to have clear understanding to a person, yes we can use what ever you have suggested and those are good option

Comment: I have initialized the variable sum as well you can use whole code and test it, it will work,

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with your code:

- Your loops are coded incorrectly.

  `for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)` should be `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)`, otherwise you end up with +1 element more than the user specified.

  And `z = v.front(); while (z != v.back()) { ... z = z + 1; }` is effectively the same as `for(z = 0; z < n; z++)`
- you are populating a `std::vector` with index numbers, but you are not really using those values for anything meaningful that you can't use your other variables for the same thing, so you may as well just eliminate the `vector` altogether.
- your `sum` variable holds the weighted score of only 1 assignment at a time, so when you `cout` it, it prints out the score of the last assignment that was entered. You are not storing the *cumulative* score of all of the assignments entered.

Try something more like this instead:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double weight;
    double grade;
    double sum = 0.0;
    int n;

    cout << "how many quizzes/projects/major assignments do you have?" << endl;
    cin >> n;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "what is the weight of test # " << i + 1 << " as a decimal" << endl;
        cin >> weight;

        cout << "what was your grade on test # " << i + 1 << endl;
        cin >> grade;

        sum += (weight * grade);
    }

    cout << sum << endl;
}
```

If you really want to use a `std::vector`, you should populate it with the actual scores, and then sum them together afterwards, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> 

using namespace std;

struct assignment
{
    double weight;
    double grade;
};

int main()
{
    vector<assignment> v;

    double sum = 0.0;
    int n;

    cout << "how many quizzes/projects/major assignments do you have?" << endl;
    cin >> n;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        assignment a;

        cout << "what is the weight of test # " << i + 1 << " as a decimal" << endl;
        cin >> a.weight;

        cout << "what was your grade on test # " << i + 1 << endl;
        cin >> a.grade;

        v.push_back(a);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        sum += (v[i].weight * v[i].grade);
    }

    cout << sum << endl;
}
```

Or:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> 

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<double> v;

    double weight;
    double grade;
    double sum = 0.0;
    int n;

    cout << "how many quizzes/projects/major assignments do you have?" << endl;
    cin >> n;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "what is the weight of test # " << i + 1 << " as a decimal" << endl;
        cin >> weight;

        cout << "what was your grade on test # " << i + 1 << endl;
        cin >> grade;

        v.push_back(weight * grade);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        sum += v[i];
    }
    // or simply:
    // #include <numeric>
    // sum = accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0.0);

    cout << sum << endl;
}
```